# Forward SMB from private interface to public interface?

Tags: iptables, router, port-forwarding, redirection

I have a router with public IP address `ADDR` and private IP address `192.168.1.1`.
I also have a public domain `DOMAIN` with an A record pointing to `ADDR`.

The router has a built-in SMB server.
I can access the SMB shares internally by typing `\\ADDR\ShareName` into Windows Explorer.
However, I want to be able to also access them via `\\DOMAIN\ShareName` internally.

Currently this doesn't work because Samba is not listening on the public interface. It only listens on the private interface, and I obviously don't want to change this and introduce a security hole.

So I redirect port 445 of `ADDR` to `192.168.1.1` when the source is in the local subnet:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -p tcp --dport 445 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:445
```

but this doesn't work for some reason, and I don't understand why. (I don't know `iptables` well.)
Why doesn't this work? And how can I make it work?

(And yes, `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` gives `1`.)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something you should try to solve using iptables. Simply have separate internal zone for your domain and make the hostname resolve to the local IP of your service.

BTW, even if iptables was the solution, your `192.168.1.1` is probably part of `192.168.1.0/24` instead of `192.168.0.0/16`.

Comment: No, I can't make the hostname resolve to the local IP. The router's internal web interface (and really, anything else that is local-only) is served on its local IP and that would clash with services that I want to make public. I really do think I need to use `iptables` here.

Comment: Then, make it `\\smb.domain` or something. Subdomains exists for that purpose.

Comment: No, I don't want to make users deal with multiple domains just for the sake of file sharing. I'd appreciate it if you could just answer the question I've asked. If you think `iptables` cannot or should not be used then I would appreciate being a clear explanation of why, rather than merely being told to do it a different way. Otherwise this doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: Hint to the right direction on the second paragraph.

Comment: I can make that change but that wouldn't fix any problem though, would it? I'm confused why you're emphasizing that.